# Drawing automata for languages

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I'm trying to draw two automata for these two languages:
[image]

For the first one, I know that the minimum is n = 1, m = 1, but I'm having troubles drawing a NFA for it.

The second one the minimum is n = 2, m = 1, but I still don't know how to start the NFA.

I have this for q2:

[image]

Comment: it might help you to realize that n-m = 0 mod 3 if and only if n mod 3 - m mod 3 = 0. So you could store n mod 3 as you loop through the a's, and then resolve the b's differently based on what you get for n mod 3. It works similarly for the second one.

Comment: You might want to ask your computer science questions at [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at small numbers first. For the second language, the first valid $(n,m)$ pairs are $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$, $(3,3)$, and all others are of the form
$(3k+n,3l+m)$, where $(n,m)$ is one of the starting pairs.

Hence the language can be described by $S \leftarrow abb|aab|aaabbb|aaaS|Sbbb$.
It should be straightforward to draw an automata from this description.

[image]

Comment: sorry I'm just having trouble deciding how many states I should have?

Comment: I think a minimal DFA would be 12 states. Just draw the automata. You can use as many states as you like.

Comment: Ah, I haven't been able to construct one yet - I am stumped

Comment: I may have been a little quick with my comment. I was about to add a DFA and realised I made a big mistake.

Comment: what do you mean you made a big mistake?

Comment: My DFA was incorrect. I think the description above is correct, but the DFA I added (and subsequently removed) was incorrect.

Comment: Oh I see haha, no worries thanks for trying, this is a tough question

Comment: I added a NFA, I didn't draw every state, but I think it is fairly clear. Note how it matches the grammar.

Comment: so is it something like the edit I made in the original post?

Comment: I don't think so, you allow an arbitrary number of $a$s at the start. I think instead of $a$ looping back you ned a chain of $a$s, and similar at the end with $b$s.